# Multiple rows with PHP foreach?

Tags: php, loops, cakephp, foreach, html-table

I am trying to make a table with 4 rows from a foreach-call.

My problem is, that in the result I get each ID twenty times in the same column.

I'm using this code:

```
<table  width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="10px">

   <?php foreach (array_chunk($items, 4) as $row) { ?>

      <?php     
         $i = 0;    
            foreach ($items as $item):      
            $class = null;      
            if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {            
            $class = ' class="altrow"';         
      } ?>

     <tr
        <?php echo $class;?>
     >  

  <?php foreach ($row as $item){ ?>         
     <td>
        <?php echo htmlentities ($item['Item']['id']); ?>
     </td>
  <?php } ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>    
</tr> 
<?php } ?> 
</table>
```

**Any idea how I could get each ID just once?**

Comment: Just as an aside, it's a lot easier and more maintainable to use jQuery to do the HTML row color striping than doing it server side with PHP.

Comment: mikel - not necessarily because yes jQuery does have features for it however it implies that javascript is enabled in the browser and that you want to have the user load the jQuery library for something that could be implemented server side.

Comment: Personal preference the I guess. Still, the jQuery way is just "$(".stripeMe tr:even").addClass("altrow");" - much easier than the PHP above to me. Still this is off-topic, I shouldn't have mentioned it really...

Comment: mikel -- not really offtopic at all.You just climbed up the ladder of abstraction from the mechanics of a specific way to do something to another member of the more general class of solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrememnting `$i` at every `$item` as opposed to every `$row`

Is this the fix you are looking for?

Edit: Mikel has your fix, add this to fix the row bug (Typical of me to notice that first eck!)

```
<table  width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="10px">
<?php 
    $i = 0;
    $chunkedarray = array_chunk($items, 4);
    foreach ($chunkedarray as $row) {      
        $class = null;      
        if ($i++ % 2 == 0)           
            $class = ' class="altrow"';
        echo "<tr ".$class.">";
        foreach ($row as $item){ 
            echo "<td>";
            echo htmlentities ($item['Item']['id']); 
            echo "</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
    }?>  
</table>
```